Slim 4: Getting the current URL for redirection after sign in
I have a Slim PHP (v4) project with several pages requiring the user being signed in. If he lands on on one of this pages (for example project.com/report) the user is taken to the sign up form. The problem is, after the user signs in, I can't find a way to redirect him to the page he intended to visit before signing in.
How can I get the initial page before redirecting to the sign in form?
This is the middleware I'm using to redirect users to the login page:
<?php
namespace App\Middleware;

use App\Middleware\Middleware;
use Slim\Routing\RouteContext;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface as RequestHandler;

class RedirectVisitorToLogin extends Middleware {
    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler) {
        $response = $handler->handle($request);

        if (!$this->c->get('auth')->check()) {
            $routeParser = RouteContext::fromRequest($request)->getRouteParser();
            $login = $routeParser->urlFor('auth.signin');
            return $response
            ->withHeader('Location', $login)
            ->withStatus(302);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}


The Request instance should be able to get you all the info you need. https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/request.html#the-request-uri

I would suggest adding request URI to a URL parameter, so if you attempt to enter https://example.com/foo?id=1, the login form URL becomes https://example.com/login?location=%2Ffoo%3Fid%3D1 and location parameter contains /foo?id=1 once decoded.
